# Which part of a laser printer causes this kind of blurry print and how to fix it? (Brother MFC-8950DW)

Tags: printing, laser-printer

My Brother MFC-8950DW printer **prints blurry**, as visible on the **left of image** attached below.

The corona wire was cleaned, as well as the drum.

After a paper jam occurred and I removed the sheet from the front of the machine, **I noticed that the impression is sharp when the toner is not (yet) attached to the page**, as visible on the **right of the attached image**. (The visible dirt is because the sheet has been balled up.)

Hence, I assume the blurry print comes from the fuser unit itself.

**My question is which part of the printer causes the blurry print**, and more specifically —assuming it is the fuser unit—, **which part of the fuser unit?**

The pressure roller was in poor condition and has already been replaced.

This video shows fixing the fuser unit by applying some grease https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkkmgreNTHY
at timing 8' and putting the sleeve back at timing 10'20''.

In the present case, **I am not sure if greasing the part inside the sleeve would suffice, or if the problem requires replacing either the sleeve or the lamp**.

Fuser units are fairly expensive, and I would prefer greasing or replacing only the faulty part of the fuser unit.

Please answer only if you already have some real experience with this type of problem, and if you have already replaced fuser (sub-)parts.
I'm looking for technical answers, with the purpose of repairing the fuser unit. Thank you.

N.B. The fuser unit is same for all higher end Brother printers of the 8th generation (85xx, 87xx, 88xx, 89xx series).

[image: Blurry print from a Brother MFC-8950DW laser printer]

Comment: Not the technical answer you're looking for, but consider static in this equation. Static can draw the carbon away from the paper, resulting in faded images.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I must admit not understanding it so far. In regard of the steps detailed here: https://www.tonergiant.co.uk/blog/2016/12/how-laser-printers-work-ultimate-guide/#tech , the right of my picture shows that the transfer of the image printed on the drum to the paper (i.e. step 6) succeeds. Step 7 (melting the toner to the paper by hot rollers) partly fails: the melting seems working, but some ink is drawn away, resulting in a faded and ghosted image. Are you talking about some possible electricity leakage that could charge the rollers of the fuser unit?

Comment: Or excess humidity in the air which is causing excess stating to be generated, atmospherically.

Comment: I am not living in an especially damp place, and my other laser printers print correctly.